# Add an open url handler to a button

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I created a button and I have applied to this button a handler to collect the data of some fields and record them in a spreadsheet. 
I wish, however, at the end of this operation, the script to open a url (summary page of the site where it is plugged into my script). 
How can I apply a link to the button via a handler?

I'm trying to do something I thought was rather simple and is proving to be an enigma. I watched through many stackoverflow pages but i haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using a "a" html element and associate it a onclick attribute.
Here is a [demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwX56YRW8Y64m_uczU-cOF5aORcDVlvw8JqyxnOY0tG_hXU4HU/exec)
and the source [here](https://script.google.com/d/1w0vnRtPSRWfiJievfKeAMEZ1JJc01a2axGH9SpFbvNyDOlOMN2YJ8eN1/edit?usp=sharing)

the essential part of the code:

```
<a href="<?=yourURL?>" target="_blank"   
onclick="google.script.run.scriptAction(this.parentNode);">click me!</a>
```